# Calling a Function in an Initialiser list in C++

Tags: c++, initialization

I was wondering if the following is safe, I need to pass some configuration into the initialisation of a member in my class. I declared a helper static function that builds the configuration arg to be passed in when the member is initialised.

So, concretely:

a.h:

```
class A
{
    Something d_member;
}
```

a.cpp

```
static Thing makeThing()
{
    Thing x;
    x.setValue(4);
    return x;
}

A::A() : d_member(makeThing()) {};
```

So, is it safe to use that helper function to temporarily build my Thing for construction. And secondly, does it make it any safer or faster to have it static?

Thanks.

Comment: If your real code looks similar to the example, one could consider adding the `Thing::Thing(int)` constructor.

Comment: Yes, this is very simplified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly fine and to be encouraged.

The only thing that static part does, assuming it's not in the class itself, and it appears not to be, is give it "internal" linkage.  This means that nobody can call it outside of the .cpp file it's in...basically ("translation unit" is the technical term, but generally that's the same as single .cpp/.o file)

Comment: Yes, I put it in the anonymous namespace actually. Which if I understand correctly is kinda equivalent to marking it static?

Comment: No, they're not equivalent.  Names in anonymous namespaces have external linkage, they're simply impossible to name outside of the translation unit they exist in.  If you could name it, you could use it.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe.

`static` controls only linking options and reduces visibility of the symbol. Usually you define as `static` any function that must not be visible/usable outside of your module.